# xsd truncate string C#

Tags: c#, xml, truncate

My program can generate a xml and this xml file must obey a xsd file.
In the xsd file, most of the fields have length restriction.
Is there a way to auto-truncate xml fields defined in xsd file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, you will have to implement it in your program.

Comment: OK. It seems that I have no choice.